# Python Loop Addition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

No matter what I do I don't seem to be able to add all the base volumes and quote volumes together easily! I want to end up with a total base volume and a total quote volume of all the data in the data frame. Can someone help me on how you can do this easily?

I have tried summing and saving the data in a dictionary first and then adding it but I just don't seem to be able to make this work!

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import json


def call_data(): # Call data from Poloniex
    global df
    datalink = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'
    df = urllib.request.urlopen(datalink)
    df = df.read().decode('utf-8')
    df = json.loads(df)
    global current_eth_price

    for k, v in df.items():
        if 'ETH' in k:
            if 'USDT_ETH' in k:
                current_eth_price = round(float(v['last']),2)
                print("Current ETH Price $:",current_eth_price)




def calc_volumes(): # Calculate the base & quote volumes
    global volume_totals
    for k, v in df.items():
        if 'ETH' in k:
            basevolume = float(v['baseVolume'])*current_eth_price
            quotevolume = float(v['quoteVolume'])*float(v['last'])*current_eth_price

            if quotevolume > 0:                
                    percentages = (quotevolume - basevolume) / basevolume * 100
                    volume_totals = {'key':[k],
                                     'basevolume':[basevolume],
                                     'quotevolume':[quotevolume],
                                     'percentages':[percentages]}

                    print("volume totals:",volume_totals)
                    print("#"*8)


call_data()
calc_volumes()
```

Comment: General tip: Avoid `global` variables like the plague. Embrace the concept of passing arguments to functions and letting functions `return` results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes:

- For the next 2 years don't use the keyword `globals` for anything.
- put function documentation under the function in quotes
- using the requests library will be much easier than urllib. However ...
- pandas can fetch the JSON and parse it all in one step
- ok it doesn't have to be as split up as this, I'm just showing you how to properly pass variables around instead of globals.
- I could not find "ETH" by itself.  In the data they sent they have these 3 ['BTC_ETH', 'USDT_ETH', 'USDC_ETH'].  So I used "USDT_ETH"  I hope the substitution is ok.
- calc_volumes is seeming to do the calculation and being some sort of filter (it's picky as to what it prints).  This function needs to be broken up in to it's two separate jobs. printing and calculating.  (maybe there was a filter step but I leave that for homework)

.

```
import pandas as pd

eth_price_url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'


def get_data(url=''):
    """ Call data from Poloniex and put it in a dataframe"""
    data = pd.read_json(url)
    return data


def get_current_eth_price(data = None):
    """ grab the price out of the dataframe """
    current_eth_price = data['USDT_ETH']['last'].round(2)
    return current_eth_price


def calc_volumes(data=None, current_eth_price=None):
    """ Calculate the base & quote volumes """
    data = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('ETH')]].loc[['baseVolume', 'quoteVolume', 'last']]
    data = data.transpose()
    data[['baseVolume','quoteVolume']]*= current_eth_price
    data['quoteVolume']*=data['last']
    data['percentages']=(data['quoteVolume'] - data['baseVolume']) / data['quoteVolume'] * 100
    return data



df = get_data(url = eth_price_url)
the_price = get_current_eth_price(data = df)
print(f'the current eth price is: {the_price}')
volumes = calc_volumes(data=df, current_eth_price=the_price)

print(volumes)
```

Comment: Hey mate @Back2Basics I just had a chance to look at the code further. It seems it's only looking at the basevolume & quotevolume for the 'USDT_ETH' column if I am understanding it correctly. I was wanting to add all basevolumes under currencies traded in ETH. Not sure how to go about it if this is the case...

Comment: This should deal with all values at once. I needed to change the return data type for that.

Comment: Thanks so much @Back2Basics that was exactly what I was looking for! I was looking for this little gem data = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('ETH')]].loc[['baseVolume', 'quoteVolume', 'last'] is there also a way to exclude something from this? Maybe not contains?

Comment: You can learn selection possibilities using & | and ^  e.g. (df.columns.str.contains('ETH')) & (df.columns.str.contains('USD'))  from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

This code seems kind of odd and inconsistent... for example, you're importing `pandas` and calling your variable `df` but you're not actually using dataframes. If you used `df = pd.read_json('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker', 'index')`* to get a dataframe, most of your data manipulation here would become much easier, and wouldn't require any loops either.

For example, the first function's code would become as simple as `current_eth_price = df.loc['USDT_ETH','last']`.

The second function's code would basically be

```
eth_rows = df[df.index.str.contains('ETH')]

total_base_volume = (eth_rows.baseVolume * current_eth_price).sum()
total_quote_volume = (eth_rows.quoteVolume * eth_rows['last'] * current_eth_price).sum()
```

(*The `'index'` argument tells pandas to read the JSON dictionary indexed by rows, then columns, rather than columns, then rows.)